# Put multiple GUI classes into one window JAVA

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, interface

I have multiple GUI classes that I wish to put into one window. I tried this by creating a "Master" gui class, which creates objects of the individual gui's I have made - however they just all display in their own seperate windows.

How do I go about adding them all to one window?

I assumed I was just creating containers, which I could then put into a master-container.

here is my code:

### StockGUI Class

```
public class StockGUI extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JTextPane currentStockValue = new JTextPane();

    Font f = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, 1, 30);

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class StockGUI
     */
    public StockGUI()
    {
        //calling the super constructor from class Frame
        super("Stock Market Display");
        //setting the window size of the GUI
        setSize(600, 600);
        //selecting a predefined layout for the GUI
        setLayout(new GridLayout());
        currentStockValue.setFont(f);
        add(currentStockValue);

        setVisible(true);
    }
```

### UserGUI class

```
public class UserGUI extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private JTextPane currentStockValue = new JTextPane();
    private JButton createUser;
    private JLabel enterUsername;
    private JTextField username;
    Font f = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, 1, 30);

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class UserGUI
     */
    public UserGUI()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        super("User Info");
        //setting the window size of the GUI
        setSize(600, 400);
        //selecting a predefined layout for the GUI
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        enterUsername = new JLabel("Enter your new username:");
        enterUsername.setFont(f);
        username = new JTextField();
        username.setFont(f);

        createUser = new JButton("Create User");
        createUser.setFont(f);
        createUser.addActionListener(this);        

        add(enterUsername);
        add(username);
        add(createUser);

        setVisible(true);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
    }
```

### GUI class

```
public class GUI extends Frame
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private UserGUI userui;
    private StockGUI stockgui;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class GUI
     */
    public GUI() 
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        super("User Info");
        //setting the window size of the GUI
        setSize(600, 400);
        //selecting a predefined layout for the GUI
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        stockgui = new StockGUI();
        userui = new UserGUI();


        //add(userui);
        //add(stockgui);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev){
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });

        setVisible(true);


    }
```

Comment: Because all your classes inherit `Frame` which is a top-level window. They need to be turned into widgets and placed inside a container class

Answer (score 0):

First of all Swing components start with "J", so you should be using a `JFrame` as the top level container.

> I assumed I was just creating containers, which I could then put into a master-container.

Yes, but the container you use to hold Swing components is a `JPanel`. So you would have a main class to create the frame and the related child panels.

In your case it looks like the `GUI` class is the main class. Then the `UserGUI` and `StockGUI` should be JPanels that can be added to the frame.

You might want to use a `CardLayout` to display these panels, then you can swap panels as required. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: I've converted the UserGUI and StockGUI  to extendd JPanel instead of Frame - now I'm getting an error in my GUI class that says "boxlayout can't be shared". If I switch to a CardLayout - how will I add my JPanels to the JFrame?

Comment: `now I'm getting an error in my GUI class that says "boxlayout can't be shared".` - so don't share the BoxLayout. You need to create two BoxLayout classes using a different panel as a parameter in the constructor. Read the section from the tutorial on `How to use BoxLayout` for more information and working examples.